# How to solve a login/database missing error regarding Sitecore Training Website?

Tags: database, authentication, sitecore, sitecore6

I get the following error while accessing the Sitecore Training Website.

> **Server Error in '/' Application.**
>   Cannot open database "SiteCoreTrainingSitecore_Core" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'sitecore'.
>   **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>   **Exception Details:** System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "SiteCoreTrainingSitecore_Core" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'sitecore'.

I have installed the Sitecore Training Website but could not find the SiteCoreTrainingSitecore_Core database in MS SQL Server Management Studio. I have also checked the IIS settings and the hosts file in the Windows folder and everything looks to be fine.

What I understand from this is that I do not have the SiteCoreTrainingSitecore_Core database on my system (simple and straightforward). But if that's missing, how (and from where) to enter it into the SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have any Sitecore databases installed at all ?

When you ran the Sitecore installer you may have selected a 'Client Only' install that installs the file-system files but not the databases.

You may want to re-install and select 'Full Install' this time.

Alternatively, you can attach each of the 3 Sitecore databases (`Core`, `Master` and `Web`) using the Management Studio and update the `/App_config/ConnectionStrings.config` file to reflect the new details.

Comment: Hey @Stephen Pope,

Thanks for your quick response! :)

Where can I find the installer for this? I checked the SDN but could not find one. (There are several links mentioned when you Google it but none of them works - as it says access denied)
And as I do not have the installer with me (I am logged in into a VM), I would probably attach the databases and try again.

Comment: As far as I was aware, the only training website I know of is a blank install of Sitecore (using the installer from the 'Downloads' section of SDN) and a Sitecore package (which you install into Sitecore after you have it up and running.). You will need your Sitecore license (license.xml) on hand when you run the installer.

If you don't have permission to download the installer (ie you dont see the 'Downloads' section in SDN) it could be because you have not passed the certified training course & dont have access yet.If you have & still cant access it you may have to contact Sitecore support.

Comment: Never mind about the installers, I got the training website running by attaching the required databases.
It was not that complicated after all.

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

As it seems, your installation does find the database, but the login failed on user Sitecore. Please check what database server you are using when installing using the installer. Log into the MSSQL environment and attach user Sitecore to the databases as DB Owner and specify a user password for this user. (Turn of password policy)

To edit your connections open the connectionstrings.config file in the App_Config directory of your website. Check the connectionstrings and compare them to what you see in MSSQL Management studio on your SQL server.

Comment: Hey @Younes,
You see, it never asks me for user credentials. After entering the URL, it directly lands up onto that error page.
I do not have the installer (I am using a VM) and would probably attach the databases and try again. 

Thanks for your quick response! :)