# Exception: .Net SqlClient Data Provider at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,

Tags: .net, sql-server, sitecore, sitecore7

I m doing sitecore 7.0 Installation with installer ...but every time on database setup it throws same error :

> Exception:  .Net SqlClient Data Provider
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean
>   enlistOK)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean
>   withFailover)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
>   timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   SitecoreInstallWizardCore.Utils.SQLUtil.TestSqlServerConnection(String
>   connectionString, String userName, Boolean verifyUserSysadmin, Boolean
>   verifyInstanceLocal)

thing i tried :

- diffrent login credentials on sql server / window authentication ..
- clean up all cache in temp

  - installed mvc 3 and 4

still the installer says given error with above error

> An error occured while attempting to connect to SQL Server: Login
>   failed for user ' '. See the log file for details.

i googled , but couldnt find much relevant regarding  sitecore ...
please suggest

Comment: Is that the log file?  What are you passing for connectionString, username ...?   That is really strange that it is giving and error Login failed for user '' if you are passing a user.  Since you don't password I would guess windows authentication.  Is that server a domain member?

Comment: Had similar error and turned out the user/password for connection I had in connection string was wrong to what it was in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable SQL server named pipes  and via protocol, just enable TCP/IP.

Got this from this link -- http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%205,-d-,3/Installation/Troubleshooting.aspx

Thoughts -- may be it first tried with named pipes and failed, but if it is disabled, it will definitely connect using TCP and that should solve the problem.

or more link -- [How to solve a login/database missing error regarding Sitecore Training Website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387512/how-to-solve-a-login-database-missing-error-regarding-sitecore-training-website)

Comment: yes ..this is related problem i guess . I in configuration manager ...the pipieline are corrupt ..ned to install sp2 , m working on it , will update the post

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if The sql server set to "windows authentification only" mode, That could be what causing this issue.
If so, You need change that to "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode", See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670(v=sql.105).aspx) for help

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a SQL connection string issue and is not related to sitecore. Check your connectionstrings.config to see if you are using integrated security(windows) or if you are passing user credentials in your connection string.